# exported object isn't available

Tags: lightning-web-components, js

Let's say we have LWC

```
export const PROGRAM_TYPE = {
ISV   : 'AppExchange',
SI : 'Consulting'
```

};

and

```
import PROGRAM_TYPE from 'c/pdxConstantsCommon';
```

inside parent component. but i'm not able to reach e.g. PROGRAM_TYPE.ISV value but

```
console.log(PROGRAM_TYPE) says
```

PROGRAM_TYPE:
ISV: "AppExchange"
SI: "Consulting"

but both PROGRAM_TYPE.SI and PROGRAM_TYPE.ISV are undefined. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

there is need to use

```
import {PROGRAM_TYPE} from 'c/pdxConstantsCommon';
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer? If you want to have a single source for these constant values I think storing them in their own module is the proper approach and that way other components can import them as needed.

Comment: there is need to share constants with another components

Comment: @nbrown curly brakes matter ;)